# Displaying Char by Char in HTML using JavaScript and then removing it with new word

Tags: javascript

I wanted to do something like this done in a Portfolio

**Check this out**

[sabbircs06.github.io/portfolio/](https://sabbircs06.github.io/portfolio/)

In the Introduction Section, It's displaying Developer. Which is **displaying char by char** after 1sec and **then selecting the displayed word, removing it** and showing next string char by char.

I am having very hard time to code this in Vanilla Js.
Kindly someone help me on that, I am ok if you use jquery for this, but Vanila js will be preferrable.

Comment: It's fairly easy to accomplish in vanilla JavaScript using timeouts and animating CSS properties.

Comment: Can you share the code

Comment: How about your example's github if you want the code ? https://github.com/sabbircs06/portfolio

Comment: @Thelostcause check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_typewriter)

Answer (score 4):

It takes a little bit of recursion, sprinkle in some timers and fiddling with some classes, but this is a pretty close approximation.

```js
let words = ["Dog", "Cat", "Parakeet", "Ferret"];

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () =>
  displayWord(document.querySelector("#adjective"))
);

function displayWord(el) {
  el.classList.remove("selected");
  const word = words.shift();
  words.push(word);
  displayLetters(el, word);
}

function displayLetters(el, word, idx = -1) {
  idx++;
  if (idx > word.length) {
    setTimeout(() => el.classList.add("selected"), 1250);
    return setTimeout(() => displayWord(el), 2000);
  }
  el.innerHTML = word.slice(0, idx);
  setTimeout(() => displayLetters(el, word, idx), 200);
}
```

```css
p {
  font-size: larger;
}

#adjective {
  font-style: italic;
}

.selected {
  background-color: rgb(180, 215, 255);
}

#caret {
  animation: blink-animation 1s steps(5, start) infinite;
}

@keyframes blink-animation {
  to {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p>I am a <span id="adjective"></span><span id="caret">|</span></p>
```

Comment: Brother thanks a lot, if you don't mind.
can you please tell me, How you solved problem like this, I am beginner in web development, I feel pity when i don't come up to the solution like that.

Comment: I've been doing this stuff for a long time. Start with the "easy" part. Put a word on the page. Then use a timer to put a new word on the page. The try to make it draw each letter. Each time, you get a little closer to the final solution. And if you run into a problem, you probably learned something when you start over.